# Advice on extracting information from web data (Swift)

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I want to find a way to extract multiple items from web data in Swift. I'm looking to extract driver IDs from the following XML data after calling the URL in swift:

view-source: http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results (view source in chrome)

Currently I have a solution which only picks out the first value. Ideally I would like to pick all the values and arrange them in an array for later use.

```
    var wasSuccessful = false

    let attemptedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results")

    if let url = attemptedUrl {

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let urlContent = data {

                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                let websiteArray = webContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("<Driver driverId=\"")

                if websiteArray!.count > 1 {

                    let driverArray = websiteArray![1].componentsSeparatedByString("\" code=")

                    if driverArray.count > 1 {

                        wasSuccessful = true

                        let driverSummary = driverArray[0]

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                            self.lblDrivers.text = driverSummary // just to confirm drivers are showing up

                        })

                    }

                }

            }

            if wasSuccessful == false {

                self.lblDrivers.text = "Sorry, we could not find the results."

            }

        }

        task.resume()

    } else { //if url couldnt be created

        self.lblDrivers.text = "Sorry, we could not find the results."

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library solves your problem well: [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi)

It support XPath and CSS queries. In your case, define a XML namespace "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4" with prefix "ns" then use a XPath query "//ns:Driver" returns all elements named `Driver` as a Sequence.

The reason we need to define a namespace is that the XML you provide has its root element in namespace "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4"

If you don't know XPath well, refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

```
import Fuzi

let attemptedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results")

if let url = attemptedUrl {
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {
      guard let data = data else {
        print("failed to get data")
        return
      }
      let doc = try XMLDocument(data: data)
      doc.definePrefix("ns", defaultNamespace: "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4")

      let drivers = doc.xpath("//ns:Driver")
      for driver in drivers {
        print(driver["driverId"])
        print(driver["code"])
        print(driver["url"])
      }

      if drivers.isEmpty {
        print("No drivers found")
      }
    } catch let error {
      print(error)
    }
  }
  task.resume()
} else { //if url couldnt be created
  print("Sorry, we could not find the results.")
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks for taking the time to write up a solution, I should now be able to use the driver data collected

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSXMLParser` for that. Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@lucascerro/understanding-nsxmlparser-in-swift-xcode-6-3-1-7c96ff6c65bc#.jxveml3ib) on how to use that class to parse an XML file.

However there is a number of libraries out there that make XML parsing a bit easier if you have never worked with NSXMLParser.

Here is a small list of XMLParser libraries that you could try out:

- https://github.com/tadija/AEXML
- https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash